# Can I create Less color themes with variables that rely on other variables?

Tags: css, less

Does anyone know how to do what I am attempting to do here?

```
#theme (dark)  {@primary: black;}
#theme (light) {@primary: white;}
#theme (@_)    {@primary: yellow;}

@name: dark;
#theme(@name);

.rule {
  color: @primary;
}
```

I am trying to define a few "themes" which will have colors and images (possibly) that will be used throughout the various `Less` files. I have made do in the past with defining them globally and commenting out those that are not in use, but I am trying to see if there are people who have found better strategies in `Less` than what I have.

I had at one point found a feature that used to be (?) a part of `Less` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.theme {
  @color: red;
}

.rule {
  color: .theme > @color;
}
```

This would be great, if it worked.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of messing with LESSCSS, I've come up with a reasonable way to change all variables based on a single `@theme` variable.

The trick is to use [variable interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation) to specify a [variable reference to a variable](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names).

```
//this can be either "dark" or "light"
@theme: dark;

@theme-primary: "@{theme}-primary"; //this will evaluate to "dark-primary"
@theme-secondary: "@{theme}-secondary"; //this will evaluate to "dark-secondary"

@dark-primary: #F00;
@dark-secondary: #000;

@light-primary: #333;
@light-secondary: #FFF;

body {
    //@theme-secondary evaluates to "dark-secondary"
    //@dark-secondary evalutates to #000
    background-color: @@theme-secondary;
    //@theme-primary evaluates to "dark-primary"
    //@dark-primary evaluates to #F00
    color: @@theme-primary;
}
```

---

#### Older version

While I don't know of an easy way to conditionally define variables, if you're going to change one word and change a color theme, you might as well change an import statement:

```
@import ’themes/dark.less’;
//@import ’themes/light.less’;
```

Comment: While I was hoping to keep it all in a single file, this isn't a bad idea really. Thank you for one possible solution.